# Expander don't expand when clicking on the header

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I have huge legacy Styles.xaml file with a weird default behavior for Expanders. To expand, you can only click on the tiny icon, not on the header.

I can't seem to find anything wrong with the Styles, so my guess is that the problem is somewhere else, can someone confirm ?

Here is the whole file [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mM1cEimQ) and here is the interesting part :

```
<!-- Expander -->

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <Path Name="Arrow" Fill="#FF4682B4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FF060606"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FF093E6A"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FF093E6A"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Name="ContentRow" Height="0"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Name="Border" Grid.Row="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}" Background="#FF4682B4" />
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Name="Content" Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,2,2">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentRow" Property="Height" Value="{Binding ElementName=Content,Path=DesiredHeight}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the template. It works as you would expect it to work. Your `ToggleButton.IsChecked` is bound to `Expander.IsExpanded` property and only when this button changes `IsChecked` state `Expander` will open/close. 
If you want to change that behaviour then you have to put whole header `ContentPresenter` as `ToggleButton.Content`. Something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
   <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
       <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <Path Name="Arrow" Fill="#FF4682B4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
           <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
       </Grid>
   </Border>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       ...
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                       <RowDefinition Name="ContentRow" Height="0"/>
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <Border Name="Border" Grid.Row="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0">
                           <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}" Background="#FF4682B4">
                               <ToggleButton.Content>
                                   <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                               </ToggleButton.Content>
                           </ToggleButton>
                   </Border>
                   <Border Name="Content" Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,2,2">
                       <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
                   </Border>
               </Grid>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                   ....
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

this way whole header becomes active `ToggleButton` and you can open/close using whole header

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are on the right track but I lack knowledge of XAML to edit the style at the beginning of the file which cause the header to disappear. I'll come back to Accept your answer if I figure it out.

Comment: If you want [this](http://pastebin.com/400KSgT1) is changed, working, XAML from your example

Answer (score 0):

Here's the template of your Expander header:

```
 <Border Name="Border" Grid.Row="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}" Background="#FF4682B4" />
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
```

As you can see, there is a `ToggleButton` bound to `IsExpanded` property, which I guess is responsible for the 'weird behaviour'

Comment: Every piece of code I found do it that way. I think the property only tell the toggle button which state to use (collapsed : arrow down or visible : arrow right).

Comment: It's declared as TwoWay, which means that Expander uses it to determine its own state